# How would you tell your regex to account for some word before the first match expressed by an other pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Here is a part of text (it is far longer in reality and i have to parse thousands of this kind) i can retrieve by ocr:

```
text= """avisd'impot2019e\n\n%ai%%a%%aimpotsurlesrevenus\ndel'annee2018\n\nretrouvezcetaviseieejae%abeeleli}jen%espubliques\nsurimpots.gouv.frsaidromorantin\npourvosdemarches,;uur\n\n\n\nilsuffitdefournirune\nphotocopie,verifiablesur\nimpots.gouv.fr/verifavis\n\nvousetesnonimposable8\n\nal'impotsurlerevenu.aceptsiganesboite257\n26ruedeplainnne\n44800romorantinlannnthenay\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nvosreferences\npouraccederavotreespaceparticulier\nnumerofiscal(c):3014347468444\n\nvotresituation\nmontantdevotreimpot\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nnd'accesenligne:voirvotredeclaration\nrevenufiscaldereference\n:760\nveuillezprendrenotedelareferencedel'avis:1941a17577893\nadressed'impositionau01/01/2019:\n\nace """
```

I am interessed by the number contained in the following portions:

1. `veuillezprendrenotedelareferencedel'avis:1941a17577893\n`
2. `revenufiscaldereference\n:760\n`

I would like to say with regex:

1. Get the 13 first  alpha-digit that follow "note" and "avis". I tried but failed with

   pattern = re.compile('(?note).*(?=avis).*[a-z0-9]{13})[^\w]')
2. Grab all the digits that follow `nufiscaldereference` , no matter if there is an `\n`.

How would you do it?

Comment: why did your pattern in (1.) fail?

Comment: Please show the expected matches from the sample input. Also, I removed the second question - ask that in another question if you like. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is `the number`? Is it `1941` or `17577893` or `194117577893` or `1941a17577893`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think I figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```
note.*?avis:([a-z\d]{13})\W|nufiscaldereference\D+(\d+)
```

and your data will be in capture groups 1 and 2 respectively.

https://regex101.com/r/LH9kKv/1

Comment: Note sure if you need `\W` after it (I see that the OP also has it though) to match 13 alpha-digit and `[^\d]+` can also be `\D+` but it does match :-) +1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Good call on `\D+` but OP has `\W` in their post so I assume they want to ensure it is exactly a 13 char alphanum code.